# Как обратиться к тэгу, используя BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://vbr.ru/banki/kurs-valut/moex/rub/'

source = requests.get(url)
main_text = source.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(main_text)

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'common-table table_highlight'})
tr = table.find('tr', {'class': 'table_adv'})

print(tr)
```

После `table.find('tr', {'class': 'table_adv'})`, `tr` стало равно:

```html
<tr class="table_adv">
    <td class="relative">
        <span class="acronym gray-text acronym_x2">USD/RUB</span>
        <a href="/banki/kurs-valut/moex/usd_rub/">Доллар США/Рубль</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>78,6905</b>
        <span class="currency-crossrate currency-crossrate-down">
            -1,4020
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>78,1454</b>
        <span class="currency-crossrate currency-crossrate-down">
            -0,5451
        </span>
    </td>
```

Как обратиться к `b`, и получить значение `78,6905`?

Comment: `tr.find("b").text`?

Comment: Victor VosMottor thanks Monica, спасибо

Comment: Учите язык XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получение того элемента можно описать css-селектором: `tr.table_adv > td > b`

Пример:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://vbr.ru/banki/kurs-valut/moex/rub/'

source = requests.get(url)
main_text = source.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(main_text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'common-table table_highlight'})
tr = table.select_one('tr.table_adv > td > b')
print(tr)
# <b>78,6905</b>

print(tr.get_text(strip=True))
# 78,6905
```